# Populating a tableView from a couchbase live query

Tags: swift, couchbase-lite

I'm new to programming so please try to explain with details or examples. I'm building an app that uses couchbase-lite to display a list of results in a tableview. I want to display any changes in the list as soon as they happen so I need to use the live query and the CBLUITableSource class. I downloaded the [Grocery Sync App](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/Grocery-Sync-iOS/tree/swift) example, but I can't quite understand how the results of the live query are displaying in the tableview. I'm also using the default master-detail template in xcode and displaying a custom cell in the tableview.

My question is how do I display the results from the live query in the table view? Do I need to use CBLUITableSource? Here's what I have so far:

My table's data soruce:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: MatchCellTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("matchcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MatchCellTableViewCell

    return cell
}
```

And the live query:

```
func initializeQuery() {
    let query = database.viewNamed("matches").createQuery()
    liveQuery = query.asLiveQuery()
    liveQuery.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rows", options: nil, context: nil)
    liveQuery.start()
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CBLUITableSource` is a convenience api to make it easier to work with live queries and table views on iOS.

Check out [this repo](https://github.com/jamiltz/LiveQueryApp) to see how to set up a table view with `CBLUITableSource`.

If you need more control over the UI update when the result of the query changes you can just use the `CBLLiveQuery` like you did :).

Comment: so, if i want two different sections, I better use `CBLLiveQuery` then `CBLUITableSource`, right?